# Is there a way I can run my tailwind CSS website outside the visual studio code IDE and Live server?

Tags: html, css, web, tailwind-css

I created a website using HTML, JS and tailwind CSS. The tailwind CSS was installed using the CLI tool following the procedures in the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) and is working fine when the page is executed with live server in Visual Studio Code.

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
```

and then created a tailwindcss.config.js with

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

Now the problem is, how do I share this whole website to a friend so that he can simply run the index.html file and he sees a completely working website running the tailwindcss code too without him having to install and configure tailwindcss. Or if there is a way to export the project with all installed packages.
Because so far, it just runs the plain html code whenever I try to share the whole project or even if I simply try to execute the page outside VsCode.

- [what I see from VsCode live server](https://i.postimg.cc/5tvRq42g/Screenshot-1.png)
- [what I see when running the page outside VsCode](https://i.postimg.cc/t48cxZp7/Screenshot-2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a possible solution to share is to host a live project on an online editor, this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-btfcun?file=index.html) uses Vite to build an environment for Tailwind and Vanilla JavaScript, it does not have much configurations but can be forked to try.

If other tools are preferred, consider start a new project in such online editor from a template with Tailwind, or start a new Node.js project and use the terminal to install needed packages.